# request with custom header does return AttributeError

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
header = {"my user - agent"}
keyword = "random torrent"
url = "".format(keyword, keyword)
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content,* "lxml")
divs = bs.select("div.g")
    
    
for d in divs:
   print(d)
   print("\n")
```

Running this code returns an AttributeException:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\ahnlu\OneDrive\desktop\code\my_project\test2.py", line 24,
> in 
> r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
>
> ```
>     AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looked up the documentaty you would see that `headers` is supposed to be a **dictionary** wich in turn has a `dict.items()` attribute:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

> If you’d like to add HTTP headers to a request, simply pass in a **dict**
> to the headers parameter.
>
> For example, we didn’t specify our user-agent in the previous example:
>
> ```
>  url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>  headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}
>
>  r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
> ```

You are using a `set` - which has no `set.items()` attribute.

**Fix:**
Use `header = {"user-agent":"my user - agent"}`

Comment: OMG.. My mistake. I wrote 'user-agent: my-app/0.0.1' -> ' user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1' That Ok .Thank you